# How to tell if an orbit is closed or opened?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

Let's assume we have an equation of orbit which is

$$\frac{1}{r} = u_o + u_1 \cos \frac{3 \theta}{2}$$

Do I have to know the value of eccentricity of the orbit to understand  the shape of the orbit? I mean if the orbit is circular or ellipse, the orbit would be closed. But my problem is that how it is different to a bound orbit.

I have found a theory that says $\Delta \phi =  2 \pi \frac{m}{n} $ can be used to find a orbit is closed or not. It says the $2 pi$ has to be a rational function.  Could you explain it more?

Or it is better to use any other equation?

Comment: see here: [How can we tell the potential from the orbit?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244626/how-can-we-tell-the-potential-from-the-orbit/244641#244641)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited  my question according to your comment. :) Could you please tell me what is $u_o$ and $u_1$ in the equation?

Comment: The easiest way to find out the shape is to plot the orbit.

Comment: see also : [What is the difference between a bounded orbit and a closed orbit?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33191)

Comment: But how to find that the orbit is closed or not from that equation?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but perhaps it'll help to point out that, given that the orbit is bounded, we know it must be closed, just because the dependence on $\theta$ is periodic. $r(\theta) = r(\theta+2 \pi n)$ for any integer $n$. This is true for orbits of the form described by your equation, but is not true for more general motions, where you can have entirely aperiodic, but still bounded, behavior. (I think that's what your $\frac m n$ equation is getting at, but that's a different scenario than the one you've posed.)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually simpler than you might think.

If we have something like 
$r=\frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{3 \theta }{2}\right)+2}$
we get a graph like

[image]

But if $u_0 \leq u_1$, then the denominator will go to zero at some point, so the radius will go to infinity, and so the path won't loop back on itself.